# Как правильно понимать определение software architecture?

Tags: архитектура, терминология

> The software architecture of a system is the set of structures needed
> to **reason about** the system, which comprise software elements,
> relations among them, and properties of both.

Архитектура программы для системы это набор структур необходимых для **размышления(рассуждения, обдумывания) о** системе, которые включают программные элементы, связи между ними и их свойства.

Какой вариант перевода лучше?
Или возможно тут важно что архитектура будет продуманна (финальный результат).

Еще пару примеров использования этой фразы:

> A structure is architectural if it supports **reasoning about** the system
> and the system’s properties.

> The **reasoning** should be **about** an attribute of the system that is
> important to some stakeholder.

> Every system can be shown to comprise elements and relations among
> them to support some type of **reasoning**.

Был похожий вопрос [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666821/what-does-the-term-reason-about-mean-in-computer-science).

Answer (score -1):

Для **рассуждения о системе**.

В процессе создания архитектуры создается терминология и некий формальный язык, связанный одновременно с предметной областью системы и с решаемой в этой предметной области задачей.

Теперь, располагая этой терминологией и формализмом, можно рассуждать о том, что происходит в системе уже на этом языке.

Например, вместо "пользователь вводит имейл, потом пароль, мы проверяем его по базе и если имейл совпал и хэш пароля верный, мы его пускаем" можно говорить - "пользователь аутентифицировался".

То есть, мы можем *рассуждать* на более высокоуровневом языке, мыслить крупными блоками.

Comment: Минусующие приглашаются в комментарии с аргументами

Comment: я не минусующий, но на мой взгляд, Вы выделили лишь одну часть из зоны ответственности. Это как на вопрос "Кто есть web-разработчик и что он делает" сказать, что это человек который шлет коммиты в репозиторий, и теперь получая новый коммит мы можем его залить на прод и насладиться новой функциональностью нашего сервиса или огорчиться новым багом))

Comment: gbg, как по мне мысль не плохая